# Doctrine - Different result to SQL when using MIN operator

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

I have a database with this schema and data:

```
CREATE TABLE `fp_demand_planning_inventory_item` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `articleID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `orderID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mhd` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


INSERT INTO `fp_demand_planning_inventory_item` (`id`, `time`, `articleID`, `orderID`, `quantity`, `mhd`)
VALUES
    (1,'2017-06-19 09:42:58',747,432,18,'2018-04-19 00:00:00'),
    (2,'2017-06-19 09:42:58',748,432,8,'2018-04-20 00:00:00'),
    (3,'2017-06-19 09:42:58',675,432,24,'2018-01-18 00:00:00'),
    (4,'2017-06-19 13:11:34',748,387,6,'2017-06-24 00:00:00'),
    (5,'2017-06-19 13:11:34',747,387,18,'2017-06-23 00:00:00'),
    (6,'2017-06-19 13:11:34',675,387,24,'2017-06-22 00:00:00');
```

Currently I can not create a fiddle, as SQLfiddle seems to be broken. There are several items in this table with the same articleID -> here articleID = 748 (line 2 + 4). I want to achieve to always select the result with the minimum MHD date. So here I want to get the result with line 4.

However when I run this query:

```
SELECT 
 ii.articleId, MIN(ii.mhd) AS min_mhd
 FROM fp_demand_planning_inventory_item ii
 WHERE ii.articleId IN (748)
 ORDER BY min_mhd ASC
```

I get the result

```
(4,'2017-06-19 13:11:34',748,387,6,'2017-06-24 00:00:00'),
```

which is the desired result. When I run this query as a DQL I get this result:

```
$rows = $this->getModelManager()->createQuery('
            SELECT 
                ii, MAX(ii.mhd) AS HIDDEN min_mhd
            FROM FpDemandPlanning\Models\InventoryItem ii
            WHERE ii.articleId IN (:articleIds)
            ORDER BY min_mhd ASC
            ')
            ->setParameter('articleIds',  748)
            ->getResult();
```

I get the result:

```
(2,'2017-06-19 09:42:58',748,432,8,'2018-04-20 00:00:00')
```

Which is not the desired result as this is line 2. Does anybody know why DQL has a completely different result than SQL and how can I determine the same data with DQL?

Answer (score 0):

Your two queries are different -- in one case, you are just selecting the article id.  In the other, you are selecting the entire row.  I would suggest writing your queries as:

```
SELECT ii.*
FROM fp_demand_planning_inventory_item ii
WHERE ii.articleId IN (748)
ORDER BY ii.mhd ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In DQL I can use ->setMaxResults(1) but this has no effect on my resultset. LIMIT 1 is not usable in the createQuery() function

Comment: I also tried the Paginator, but setMaxResults(1) results here in the result of only one entity - even when $articleIds has more IDs.